# Connecting Intel Galileo to Mac

Tags: macos, intel-galileo

I am trying to connect an [Intel Galileo board](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/do-it-yourself/galileo-maker-quark-board.html) to a Mac via the Galileo ethernet port which connects through to a thunderbolt ethernet port on the Mac. I have uploaded an Arduino sketch to start the LAN connection:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// the media access control (ethernet hardware) address for the Galileo:
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };  
//the IP address for the Galileo:
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 2 };    

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Attempting to start Ethernet");
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        Serial.println("Attempting to configure Ethernet using Static IP");
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    }
    Serial.print("Your IP address: ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop () {}
```

In my network settings, do I put my thunderbolt ethernet as DHCP? or manually enter an ip address? What would be the ip address of my galileo so that I can ssh to it?